# git bash on windows 10, yarn command not found what should ı do?

Tags: command, git-bash

On Git Bash, ı need to **yarn start** command but the yarn command **wasn't found**. What should ı do? (I am using windows 10 operating system)

Comment: Add it to PATH!

Comment: How can ı do that?

Comment: I solved the issue by installing yarn. thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by installing yarn package
[Here is the link you can install](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable)